# What is the purpose of libc_nonshared.a?

Tags: c, glibc, libc

Why does `libc_nonshared.a` exist? What purpose does it serve? I haven't been able to find a good answer for its existence online.

As far as I can tell it provides certain symbols (`stat`, `lstat`, `fstat`, `atexit`, etc.). If someone uses one of these functions in their code, it will get linked into the final executable from this archive. These functions are part of the POSIX standard and are pretty common so I don't see why they wouldn't just be put in the shared or static `libc.so.6` or `libc.a`, respectively.

Comment: The [INSTALL](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/a6917c82b32b197bbe2bb682dd26bcfbb0fde5e6/INSTALL) file describes it as "the parts of the
     library which are always statically linked into applications and
     libraries even with shared linking", which explains why it shouldn't be in `libc.a`, but that doesn't really answer the deeper question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was a legacy mistake in glibc's implementing extensibility for the definition of `struct stat` before better mechanisms (symbol redirection or versioning) were thought of. The definitions of the `stat`-family functions in `libc_nonshared.a` cause the version of the structure to bind at link-time, and the definitions there call the `__xstat`-family functions in the real shared libc, which take an extra argument indicating the desired structure version. This implementation is **non-conforming** to the standard since each shared library ends up gettings its own copy of the `stat`-family functions with their own addresses, breaking the requirement that pointers to the same function evaluate equal.

Comment: What about the functions in `libc_nonshared.a` such as `atexit`? Is that also a victim of non-conformance? So, would a better name for that library be libc_nonstandard.a?

Comment: I don't see how you could fix that with any mechanism. The `stat` family of functions has this nice property of depending on which version you call, the _size of the buffer differs_. So passing a pointer to a stat function to another module compiled at a different time simply isn't going to work.

Comment: This was necessary to permit file size to exceed 4GB and uid/gid to exceed 64k and for time_t to become 64 bit.

Comment: @Joshua: This hack predates 64-bit `off_t` and `time_t`; by the time it was realized `off_t` would need to change size, symbol redirection had been invented, and it's a **much better** solution because it binds at compile-time rather than link-time (link-time gives the wrong result for code in static libraries).

Comment: @Joshua: Regarding passing pointers across code using different versions, of course that can't work. Making Frankenstein-binaries like that work is always at best a best-effort deal. But the solution in `libc_nonshared.a` breaks function pointer equality *even in binaries where all modules are using matching definitions*.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: It's for `dlopen()` to not yield nasty surprises. If you use browser plugins there's a good chance you used to depend on this.

Comment: @Joshua: You already get nasty surprises with `dlopen` on glibc anyway; `dlsym` for `"stat"` will give you the legacy 32-bit `off_t` function if it works at all, and likewise for `"lseek"`, etc. This problem is entirely solvable with symbol redirection though; just redirect `dlsym` exactly the same way to a version that makes the same mappings, as was done for musl libc's time64 transition on 32-bit systems: https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/ldso/dynlink.c?id=v1.2.2#n2293

Answer (score 16):

Here's the problem. Long ago, members of the `struct stat` structure had different sizes than they had today. In particular:

`uid_t` was 2 bytes (though I think this one was fixed in the transition from libc5 to glibc)
`gid_t` was 2 bytes
`off_t` was 4 bytes
`blkcnt_t` was 4 bytes
`time_t` was 4 bytes

also, `timespec` wasn't used at all and there was no room for nanosecond precision.

So all of these had to change. The only real solution was to make different versions of the `stat()` system call and library function and you get the version you compiled against. That is, the `.a` file matches the header files. These things didn't all change at once, but I think we're done changing them now.

You can't really solve this by a macro because the structure name is the same as the function name; and `inline` wasn't mandated to exist in the beginning so glibc couldn't demand everybody use it.

I remember there used to be this thing `O_LARGEFILE` for saying you could handle files bigger than 4GB; otherwise things just wouldn't work. We also used to have to define things like `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` but it's all handled automatically now. Back in the day, if you weren't ready for large file support yet, you didn't define these and you didn't get the 64-bit version of the `stat` structure; and also worked on older kernel versions lacking the new system calls. I haven't checked; it's possible that 32-bit compilation still doesn't define these automatically, but 64-bit always does.

So you probably think; okay, fine, just don't franken-compile stuff? Just build everything that goes into the final executable with the same glibc version and largefile-choice. Ever use plugins such as browser plugins? Those are pretty much guaranteed to be compiled in different places with different compiler and glibc versions and options; and this didn't require you to upgrade your browser and replace all its plugins at the same time.