# Non-standard g++ environment cannot find libc_nonshared.a

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ld

### Goal

I'm building a portable Linux c++ environment for a course to avoid `sudo` bureaucracy at our site and have a ready-made solution with VSCode included. I've done this with success for a Python course and a Julia course (see [Juliawin](https://github.com/heetbeet/juliawin)), but g++ seems to be a different beast.

### Bundling dependencies

I used a technique to download all `.deb` programs and libraries (like `build-essential`, `liblapack-dev`
and `libblas-dev`) along with their dependencies and extracted it into a pseudo root directory, e.g. 
[image]

### Environment wrapper

I then created a bash script `emdw-deps` to allow a user to activate this environment via `source emdw-deps`. In this script, I set a bunch of environment variables for our build tools to pick up all the headers and libraries included in this system. Specifically, I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, `C_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CPLUS_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`, `INCLUDE`, `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`, `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, `PATH`, `CC`, and `CXX`.

### Cannot link libc_nonshared.a

This allows me access to all my bundled tools from a terminal session. E.g. when I type `which g++`, I get the portable location:

```
/home/emdw/Downloads/portable_cpp/linux/usr/bin/g++
```

This also allows me to get the linker to link to all the bundled libraries, shared libraries, and headers. However, `ld` keeps throwing a linking error for what seems to be a hardcoded location `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a`. This is the output I get when I compile this [hello world example](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Text#C.2B.2B):

```
$ g++ hello.cpp -o hello
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### The symptom

If I make a symlink from my bundled `libc_nonshared.a` to the system path:

```
sudo ln /home/emdw/Downloads/portable_cpp/linux/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a -s
```

Then I can successfully compile `hello.cpp`

```
$ g++ hello.cpp -o hello
$ ./hello
Hello world!
```

Since I work on a clean Linux Mint VM with no software installed, I can confirm that this is indeed a successful compilation from my portable pipeline with only `libc_nonshared.a` as a non-portable hardcoded component. This is obviously not a solution, but only a way to point to the real problem.

### Question

Are there any environment variables or compiler flags that can allow me to point the build tools to an alternative location for `libc_nonshared.a`?

Comment: `g++ hello.cpp -o hello -L/home/emdw/Downloads/portable_cpp/linux/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: @TedLyngmo That gives the exact same error. (Also, that path is already available to g++ via `CPLUS_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.) It seems to somehow be hardcoded in `ld`...

Comment: Ok, then I don't see how the symlink you placed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` that points at `/home/emdw/Downloads/portable_cpp/linux/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a` could have helped.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I can't see that either other than `ld` having a hardcoded path to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a` baked into the binary, or some hardcoded search locations for `libc_nonshared.a`, or instructions to ignore any flags or environmental variables for `libc_nonshared.a`. It also seems like `libc_nonshared.a` is always included in any compilation of any c++ (and c) file. It might have something to do with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701091

Comment: The whole  library seems like a legacy one.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701284/7582247). What version of `g++` is it?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Comment: Ok, I have g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0 - Perhaps that's worth a try? There's also clang++ Ubuntu clang version 11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1. Both are available directly with `apt`

Comment: Will give it a shot

Comment: g++ 10 doesn't fix the problem, it still tries to access `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a`

Comment: And if you do `apt list -a libc6-dev` which one is installed? Also what does `dpkg --listfiles libc6-dev | wc -l` show? I get `586` (and `libc_nonshared.a` is one of them)

Comment: `... 'libc6-dev' is not installed`. This is expected, since everything is portable and build on a clean VM. I collect all the relevant .deb files through [this technique](https://askubuntu.com/a/334163/580182), extracted them into a pseudo root directory, and [building a wrapper over this directory](https://gist.github.com/heetbeet/96d780cc76ae2e1e34eb2425ac1b8b9c). This wrapper can be sourced through a terminal `source path/to/wrapper` to allow access to all the libs/bins/headers. This setup is correct since I can compile really complex projects with it, except for the `libc_nonshared.a` bug.

Comment: Hmm, seems like something you could do and maintain simpler with `docker`. Start with the official `ubuntu` image and install the tools you need on top of it and save the result as your portable wrapper